# Authentication testing with Meteor

Tags: testing, meteor, mocha.js, velocity

I'm writing meteor tests that require authentication, and having a series of problems.
This is my code:

```
MochaWeb?.testOnly ->
  describe "Login", ->
    describe "security", ->
    it 'should take you to /login/ if you are not logged in', ->
      Meteor.flush()
      chai.assert.equal Router.current().url, '/login/'

    it 'should allow logins and then take us to /', ->
      Meteor.flush()
      Accounts.createUser username: 'test', password: 'test'
      Meteor.loginWithPassword 'test', 'test', (err) ->
        console.log err
        chai.expect(err).to.be undefined
        chai.assert.equal Router.current().url, '/'
```

1. My tests pass, even though I get console messages such as Exception in delivering result of invoking 'login': TypeError: object is not a function
2. My console.log call gives me

   {error: 403, reason: "User not found", details: undefined, message: "User not found [403]", errorType: "Meteor.Error"…}

on the console, and nothing on the velocity log window

3. My user doesn't authenticate as I'd expect. One cause could be that my app doesn't have the accounts-password package, because I don't want it (I just want google apps users to be able to login). However I want an easy way to handle authentication in meteor tests, as most of my tests involve authenticated users.
4. I'm not sure whether the assert equal would work or I'd have to set some sort of timeout to wait for the redirection. In this case it wouldn't be a problem, but do I have to nest every test method I have inside loginWithPassword? I'd find this a bit uncomfortable.

Any help and suggestions much appreciated!

Best,

Comment: Hey where you able to make the test successfull,
Thanks

Comment: I'm not really convinced by any of the solutions, which is why I haven't tried them yet. I really think there should be a way to get logged in status out of the way and concentrate on the actual testing, as mature frameworks have. In the meantime, I'm trying to avoid this kind of testing in Meteor.

Comment: check my below link
https://github.com/trinisofttechnologies/mocha-test/blob/master/tests/mocha/client/client.coffee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MochaWeb.testOnly(function() {
    describe("Client", function() {
        describe("firstTest", function() {
            // Meteor.users.remove({});
            before(function(done) {
                Accounts.createUser(currentUser, function(err, success) {
                    Meteor.loginWithPassword(currentUser, function(err) {
                        console.log("This works");
                        // done(); 
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Here is the source file, in which I have implemented the same
https://github.com/trinisofttechnologies/mocha-test/blob/master/tests/mocha/client/client.coffee

and this is the repo where the code resides
https://github.com/trinisofttechnologies/mocha-test

Comment: I think it's still awkward but the best answer.
Perhaps we can put this into a common function so that we can endup with before(create_user_and_signin) and then just go on with our testing (and general lives)? that would be getting close to rails' most convenient sign_in helper

Comment: not sure what your requirement is, but for me this was the requirement,
and hence, I made test cases based on this one. Let me know what is your case, so that I can provide you with accurate test code.

Comment: I'm not trying to test the accounts system itself, but to get authentication out of the way as easily as possible in order to test methods that assume an authenticated user.

Comment: hmm, you are getting a wrong impression here, I am trying to achieve the same here, I also want to test methods, publish which require login assistance.

Comment: I see, but I'm sure you would agree that nesting the relevant code inside two blocks is not ideal by any means. I'd like look into structuring things in such a way that I can get this part out of the way with a single line of code.

Comment: the `loginWithPassword` function has changed signatures. http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-loginWithPassword

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have user already created? I think you should create it in your fixture.js.